# Can you charge batteries in series?

Tags: batteries

I am wondering if it is possible to charge batteries in series. I have a charger similar to https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSx7HKYoPIqSW1ITif_RwDzEsAz9GjIqVlMX64S2PrVg9PX0xIs It has the slides that adjust to the size of the battery. The battery that I need to charge is small enough that I can fit two batteries within a single slide. I was wondering if this is OK to charge 4 batteries at once (two in each slide). Will it ruin my batteries or fry the charger or anything like that?

Comment: A simple existence proof is consumer electronic devices that have series battery packs, which they recharge.  Also note that car batteries have multiple cells in series. The individual cell in a car battery only goes up to about 2 volts, so there are six of them in series.

Comment: An important point to bear in mind here is that while there are several examples of serial battery packs such as car batteries for example.  When batteries (or cells) are wired in series they lose charge at the same rate so can theoretically (at least) be recharged in series.  If these cells have different charge levels; because they have for example been used in different equipment; this will not be true so it's probably not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can charge batteries in series but in a charger designed for the correct voltage since the charges is meant to charge 1.2~1.5v (1 battery) it won't charge 2.4~3v packs (2 batteries)